# Why have a public method return null for a privileged method?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Looking at the MeteorJS code for the blaze package, I noticed right below this view class that there was a public method returning null for `_render`. Whats the purpose?

```
Blaze.View = function (name, render) {
  if (! (this instanceof Blaze.View))
    // called without `new`
    return new Blaze.View(name, render);

  if (typeof name === 'function') {
    // omitted "name" argument
    render = name;
    name = '';
  }
  this.name = name;
  this._render = render;

  this._callbacks = {
    created: null,
    rendered: null,
    destroyed: null
  };
```

and then right below it :

```
Blaze.View.prototype._render = function () { return null; };
```

Comment: Looks like it's just a default implementation (that doesn't do anything), seeing as you're expected to provide your own implementation to the `Blaze.View()` constructor.

Comment: Probably just a case of the developer being a bit overzealous. Looks like render will be overwritten no matter what.